# Partially Signing multisig rawtransaction returns redeemScript/witnessScript does not match scriptPubKey

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, multi-signature, createrawtransaction, signrawtransaction

I want to partially sign a rawtransactions using bitcoind through RPC but I am really stuck almost at the end of the process when I try to sign my manually created raw transaction and I spent many hours trying to find the error but I do not understand it. I am going to replicate here all the steps I did.

1. First I create a 2-3 multisig address

```
$user1_pubkey = "03e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb2";
$user2_pubkey = "02df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea2946210";
$user3_pubkey = $this->bitcoin->getaddressinfo("2Msqe8jLEReQpD4CYnRj29cAqQS8c81zidv")['pubkey'];
$keys[] = $user1_pubkey;
$keys[] = $user2_pubkey;
$keys[] = $user3_pubkey;
$multisig_address = $this->bitcoin->addmultisigaddress(2, $keys);

Returned values:

["address"]=>
    string(35) "2NBet88aY57CSYCkH7nXKb2Bxae4K3xdRBT"
    ["redeemScript"]=>
    string(210) "522103e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb22102df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea29462102102c099a12b6cba679ad56d8e793847f422634bc84b42cb3fae0b00a6943f56921253ae"
```

2. I have sent two small transactions to the multisig address (one of 0.005 and another of 0.004)

```
ef669e71fb08a2dd7b9d2500a86d53ba75e41c3ab67b4ec58435904d87b749c4
8a9e837e94a639cd104631a29b57a86d55b5dc32b8372b7ec3bacdf777ba57e5
```

3. Now I retrieve all the information related to those txids:

```
$transaction1 = $this->bitcoin->getrawtransaction("ef669e71fb08a2dd7b9d2500a86d53ba75e41c3ab67b4ec58435904d87b749c4", true);
$transaction2 = $this->bitcoin->getrawtransaction("8a9e837e94a639cd104631a29b57a86d55b5dc32b8372b7ec3bacdf777ba57e5", true);
```

3.1. Result of previous variables:

```
$transaction1 =>

array(14) {
  ["txid"]=>
  string(64) "ef669e71fb08a2dd7b9d2500a86d53ba75e41c3ab67b4ec58435904d87b749c4"
  ["hash"]=>
  string(64) "e586e88456cef32c01820d94541296aab85d776d890d8879184b8e70344a6353"
  ["version"]=>
  int(2)
  ["size"]=>
  int(247)
  ["vsize"]=>
  int(166)
  ["weight"]=>
  int(661)
  ["locktime"]=>
  int(1891405)
  ["vin"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["txid"]=>
      string(64) "9d0c2b8203b1b8f63ac8a8dc17a0e48b36efceee43d38fde50a6b3c92f811830"
      ["vout"]=>
      int(0)
      ["scriptSig"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(44) "0014839c3b61637073d6aec4c74a5b2e8fe52fcc4d83"
        ["hex"]=>
        string(46) "160014839c3b61637073d6aec4c74a5b2e8fe52fcc4d83"
      }
      ["txinwitness"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(142) "3044022055bbad9ea94df56180ded2760dd77b0fc959e633b459bc906e6bd4456f72c71302201d9430ac2ed9debc9508442484accac54021c990e8906ebbf7a6b205ec9e827101"
        [1]=>
        string(66) "0326ae8d30a90a6926b81718dfa07b0b5058636f9c86465a1c3f37b0322af023c8"
      }
      ["sequence"]=>
      int(4294967294)
    }
  }
  ["vout"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["value"]=>
      float(0.005)
      ["n"]=>
      int(0)
      ["scriptPubKey"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(60) "OP_HASH160 c9ebaa3be1c12351c9e07ea5758a68eb20ee5098 OP_EQUAL"
        ["hex"]=>
        string(46) "a914c9ebaa3be1c12351c9e07ea5758a68eb20ee509887"
        ["reqSigs"]=>
        int(1)
        ["type"]=>
        string(10) "scripthash"
        ["addresses"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(35) "2NBet88aY57CSYCkH7nXKb2Bxae4K3xdRBT"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["value"]=>
      float(0.01040373)
      ["n"]=>
      int(1)
      ["scriptPubKey"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(60) "OP_HASH160 301c49c04ede304bdef0ab48e2b365a9eef737e4 OP_EQUAL"
        ["hex"]=>
        string(46) "a914301c49c04ede304bdef0ab48e2b365a9eef737e487"
        ["reqSigs"]=>
        int(1)
        ["type"]=>
        string(10) "scripthash"
        ["addresses"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(35) "2MwdcJyxRAxqQ4tf6TQSubcLMZd21MrTskx"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["hex"]=>
  string(494) "020000000001013018812fc9b3a650de8fd343eeceef368be4a017dca8c83af6b8b103822b0c9d0000000017160014839c3b61637073d6aec4c74a5b2e8fe52fcc4d83feffffff0220a107000000000017a914c9ebaa3be1c12351c9e07ea5758a68eb20ee509887f5df0f000000000017a914301c49c04ede304bdef0ab48e2b365a9eef737e48702473044022055bbad9ea94df56180ded2760dd77b0fc959e633b459bc906e6bd4456f72c71302201d9430ac2ed9debc9508442484accac54021c990e8906ebbf7a6b205ec9e827101210326ae8d30a90a6926b81718dfa07b0b5058636f9c86465a1c3f37b0322af023c84ddc1c00"
  ["blockhash"]=>
  string(64) "00000000b1c75e4431f9c23a75779c964fa51cd714f9703781670f1a2c50a8c7"
  ["confirmations"]=>
  int(388)
  ["time"]=>
  int(1605141275)
  ["blocktime"]=>
  int(1605141275)
}


$transaction2 =>

array(14) {
  ["txid"]=>
  string(64) "8a9e837e94a639cd104631a29b57a86d55b5dc32b8372b7ec3bacdf777ba57e5"
  ["hash"]=>
  string(64) "0e8dfd742d3ea5f12ee7c033112f5e6f585b41e317b3f9d3fef61db4200c4bbd"
  ["version"]=>
  int(2)
  ["size"]=>
  int(247)
  ["vsize"]=>
  int(166)
  ["weight"]=>
  int(661)
  ["locktime"]=>
  int(1891405)
  ["vin"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["txid"]=>
      string(64) "ef669e71fb08a2dd7b9d2500a86d53ba75e41c3ab67b4ec58435904d87b749c4"
      ["vout"]=>
      int(1)
      ["scriptSig"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(44) "0014c7f49ae39660b15632f46a3c69a67ccb4de7dc20"
        ["hex"]=>
        string(46) "160014c7f49ae39660b15632f46a3c69a67ccb4de7dc20"
      }
      ["txinwitness"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(142) "304402207cc7558274cd9458c44bf7554d0b049bba1388cd82057b3f8d0786bc28690aad022057eea44e01ff11c608e254a844b620f428fb515db6ef33cd199c57d3008ce89c01"
        [1]=>
        string(66) "0303c01176f2db9efaa18e169e0ea7da87784208e05fcb1e0258ccb834805ed02d"
      }
      ["sequence"]=>
      int(4294967294)
    }
  }
  ["vout"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["value"]=>
      float(0.004)
      ["n"]=>
      int(0)
      ["scriptPubKey"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(60) "OP_HASH160 c9ebaa3be1c12351c9e07ea5758a68eb20ee5098 OP_EQUAL"
        ["hex"]=>
        string(46) "a914c9ebaa3be1c12351c9e07ea5758a68eb20ee509887"
        ["reqSigs"]=>
        int(1)
        ["type"]=>
        string(10) "scripthash"
        ["addresses"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(35) "2NBet88aY57CSYCkH7nXKb2Bxae4K3xdRBT"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["value"]=>
      float(0.00640207)
      ["n"]=>
      int(1)
      ["scriptPubKey"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(60) "OP_HASH160 0f670955696f3835ef9204dad881b1c9f3002cc7 OP_EQUAL"
        ["hex"]=>
        string(46) "a9140f670955696f3835ef9204dad881b1c9f3002cc787"
        ["reqSigs"]=>
        int(1)
        ["type"]=>
        string(10) "scripthash"
        ["addresses"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(35) "2MtefZG3K2Zs38dYntJwJKg1WqSEqNoW9sF"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["hex"]=>
  string(494) "02000000000101c449b7874d903584c54e7bb63a1ce475ba536da800259d7bdda208fb719e66ef0100000017160014c7f49ae39660b15632f46a3c69a67ccb4de7dc20feffffff02801a06000000000017a914c9ebaa3be1c12351c9e07ea5758a68eb20ee509887cfc409000000000017a9140f670955696f3835ef9204dad881b1c9f3002cc7870247304402207cc7558274cd9458c44bf7554d0b049bba1388cd82057b3f8d0786bc28690aad022057eea44e01ff11c608e254a844b620f428fb515db6ef33cd199c57d3008ce89c01210303c01176f2db9efaa18e169e0ea7da87784208e05fcb1e0258ccb834805ed02d4ddc1c00"
  ["blockhash"]=>
  string(64) "00000000b1c75e4431f9c23a75779c964fa51cd714f9703781670f1a2c50a8c7"
  ["confirmations"]=>
  int(388)
  ["time"]=>
  int(1605141275)
  ["blocktime"]=>
  int(1605141275)
}
```

4. I want to create a raw transaction to spend both utxos and I want to spent it in two different address. So having in mind the fee for the transaction I proceed to create manually the transaction.

```
        $fee = number_format(floatval($this->bitcoin->estimateSmartFee(6)['feerate'])/5, 8);
        $raw_amount = 0.00000000;
        $txids = [];
        $vouts = [];
        $amounts = [];
        $scriptPubs = [];
        for($i=0; $i<count($transactions); $i++){
            $total_amount+=$transactions[$i]["vout"][0]["value"];
            $txids[] = $transactions[$i]["txid"];
            $vouts[] = $transactions[$i]["vout"][0]["n"];
            $amounts[] = $transactions[$i]["vout"][0]["value"];
            $scriptPubs[] = $transactions[$i]["vout"][0]["scriptPubKey"]["hex"];
        }

        $inputs = '[';
        for($i=0; $i<count($vouts); $i++){
            $inputs.='{
                        "txid": "'.$txids[$i].'",
                        "vout": '.$vouts[$i].'
                      }';
            if($i+1!=count($vouts)){
                $inputs.=',';
            }
        }
        $inputs.=']';

        $minus_fee = $raw_amount-floatval($fee);
        $amount1 = $minus_fee*0.6;
        $amount2 = $minus_fee*0.4;

        $address1 = "tb1qhjcqny2rvaqd7q0700m968e3vuqctmuhhyk9fk";
        $address2 = "tb1q2nrysxf8nwxv8euwtu470wgjruw25guxkal3wd";
        $outputs = '{
                      "'.$address1.'": '.$amount1.',
                      "'.$address2.'": '.$amount2.'
                    }';

        $raw_transaction = $this->bitcoin->createrawtransaction(json_decode($inputs), json_decode($outputs));
```

4.1. Result of $raw_transaction is the following:

```
0200000002c449b7874d903584c54e7bb63a1ce475ba536da800259d7bdda208fb719e66ef0000000000ffffffffe557ba77f7cdbac37e2b37b832dcb5556da8579ba2314610cd39a6947e839e8a0000000000ffffffff02e83c080000000000160014bcb00991436740df01fe7bf65d1f31670185ef97f07d050000000000160014b92b9f7f7bf6e4e1cdd73d3d23a1dbc98aa57d4e00000000
```

5. I decode $raw_transaction

```
$decoded = $this->bitcoin->decoderawtransaction($raw_transaction);
```

Content of $decoded:

```
array(9) {
  ["txid"]=>
  string(64) "ba11b2caf11d79c1f4bc349f40895c380218e9ab91ec4c1d52aaee8284749549"
  ["hash"]=>
  string(64) "ba11b2caf11d79c1f4bc349f40895c380218e9ab91ec4c1d52aaee8284749549"
  ["version"]=>
  int(2)
  ["size"]=>
  int(154)
  ["vsize"]=>
  int(154)
  ["weight"]=>
  int(616)
  ["locktime"]=>
  int(0)
  ["vin"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["txid"]=>
      string(64) "ef669e71fb08a2dd7b9d2500a86d53ba75e41c3ab67b4ec58435904d87b749c4"
      ["vout"]=>
      int(0)
      ["scriptSig"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["hex"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["sequence"]=>
      int(4294967295)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["txid"]=>
      string(64) "8a9e837e94a639cd104631a29b57a86d55b5dc32b8372b7ec3bacdf777ba57e5"
      ["vout"]=>
      int(0)
      ["scriptSig"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["hex"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["sequence"]=>
      int(4294967295)
    }
  }
  ["vout"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["value"]=>
      float(0.0053988)
      ["n"]=>
      int(0)
      ["scriptPubKey"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(42) "0 bcb00991436740df01fe7bf65d1f31670185ef97"
        ["hex"]=>
        string(44) "0014bcb00991436740df01fe7bf65d1f31670185ef97"
        ["reqSigs"]=>
        int(1)
        ["type"]=>
        string(18) "witness_v0_keyhash"
        ["addresses"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(42) "tb1qhjcqny2rvaqd7q0700m968e3vuqctmuhhyk9fk"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["value"]=>
      float(0.0035992)
      ["n"]=>
      int(1)
      ["scriptPubKey"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["asm"]=>
        string(42) "0 b92b9f7f7bf6e4e1cdd73d3d23a1dbc98aa57d4e"
        ["hex"]=>
        string(44) "0014b92b9f7f7bf6e4e1cdd73d3d23a1dbc98aa57d4e"
        ["reqSigs"]=>
        int(1)
        ["type"]=>
        string(18) "witness_v0_keyhash"
        ["addresses"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(42) "tb1qhy4e7lmm7mjwrnwh857j8gwmex922l2wwc830y"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

6. Now I proceed to partially sign the previous created transaction.

```
        $private_key = $this->bitcoin->dumpprivkey("2Msqe8jLEReQpD4CYnRj29cAqQS8c81zidv"); // cS6e5CojfNy2ELWcsB4tLFVQV9wSSQUw1PU4YrSwRSjYLaC8ikrU
        $redeemScript = "522103e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb22102df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea29462102102c099a12b6cba679ad56d8e793847f422634bc84b42cb3fae0b00a6943f56921253ae";
        $vin = $raw_transaction["vin"];
        $vout = $raw_transaction["vout"];

        $prevtxs = '[';
        for($i=0; $i<count($txids); $i++){
            $prevtxs .= '{
                    "txid": "'.$txids[$i].'",
                    "vout": '.$vouts[$i].',
                    "scriptPubKey": "'.$scriptPubs[$i].'", 
                    "redeemScript": "'.$redeemScript.'",
                    "amount": '.$amounts[$i].'
                  }';
            if($i+1!=count($txids)){
                $json2.=',';
            }
        }
        $prevtxs.=']';

        $partially_signed = $this->bitcoin->signrawtransactionwithkey($raw_transaction, json_decode($private_key), json_decode($prevtxs));
```

7. And in the previous step is where the process fails. The transaction is not signed and the bitcoind returns this error:

```
redeemScript/witnessScript does not match scriptPubKey
```

I am using bitcoin testnet to test it and I think that I added all the information. If someone knows where it is the mistake, please let me know. I searched information to fix it but I could not find a solution for my issue.

Edited:
I followed the next [tutorial](https://btcinformation.org/en/developer-examples#p2sh-multisig) where I could notice that I was using the wrong scriptpub and I retrieved funding inputs using getrawtransaction passing the second argument (true) to get the decoded transaction. And well, now the previous error is gone but now it throws a new error: `redeemScript/witnessScript does not match scriptPubKey`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your redeem script hash should be:

> RIPEMD160(SHA256(0x522103e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb22102df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea29462102102c099a12b6cba679ad56d8e793847f422634bc84b42cb3fae0b00a6943f56921253ae))
> = **0bf37781383277cbb4e544c402f5265a51f4d828**

Which results this address:

```
2MtLR5mKgWRZBYtCYiSuaKpTUSuney9Cg2V
```

However you somehow end up with this hash:

> **c9ebaa3be1c12351c9e07ea5758a68eb20ee5098**

Which results this address:

```
2NBet88aY57CSYCkH7nXKb2Bxae4K3xdRBT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I did not know that I should hash the redeem script, so I am trying to replicate the steps you followed: ```hash('ripemd160', hash('sha256', '0x522103e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb22102df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea29462102102c099a12b6cba679ad56d8e793847f422634bc84b42cb3fae0b00a6943f56921253ae'))``` but it returned )``` 3ad9a694cd5881032106e839f834600141b533e3)``` instead of your hash. I am using PHP but I do not think that it is my problem. Any idea?

Comment: About this hash ```c9ebaa3be1c12351c9e07ea5758a68eb20ee5098``` and the address ```2NBet88aY57CSYCkH7nXKb2Bxae4K3xdRBT``` it seems that it comes from the information from trannsactions in the multisig address

Comment: "3ad9a694cd5881032106e839f834600141b533e3" is the result of string message digest. Set "raw_output" true in order to calculate hex message digest. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again but I still do not see it. First I followed your advice and I enabled raw_out which gave me the binary output, then I converted it to hex: ```bin2hex(hash('ripemd160', hash('sha256', '0x522103e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb22102df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea29462102102c099a12b6cba679ad56d8e793847f422634bc84b42cb3fae0b00a6943f56921253ae', true), true));``` but it did not return the desired value, I also tried adding and removing "0x" from the redeen script but it did not work.

Comment: And I tried all combinations with sha256 using raw_out and the other not etc On the other hand, I replaced my current redeemscript value for the one that you gave me ```0bf37781383277cbb4e544c402f5265a51f4d828``` but I still get the same error

Comment: Try:
hash('ripemd160', hex2bin(hash('sha256', hex2bin('522103e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb22102df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea29462102102c099a12b6cba679ad56d8e793847f422634bc84b42cb3fae0b00a6943f56921253ae'))));

Comment: Perfect! It returns the same hash you posted! :) But unfortunately when I pass the new hash as redeemscript to signtransaction function it returns the same error. I just followed the same process that I described here, but just changing the content of $redeemScript from ```522103e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb22102df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea29462102102c099a12b6cba679ad56d8e793847f422634bc84b42cb3fae0b00a6943f56921253ae``` to ```0bf37781383277cbb4e544c402f5265a51f4d828```

Answer (score 0):

*2MtLR5mKgWRZBYtCYiSuaKpTUSuney9Cg2V* is your new address which is derived from scriptHash `0x0bf37781383277cbb4e544c402f5265a51f4d8289`. Go all the way back to step 2 and send 0.005 & 0.004 to *2MtLR5mKgWRZBYtCYiSuaKpTUSuney9Cg2V*. scriptPubKey of those transactions will be both `OP_HASH160 0bf37781383277cbb4e544c402f5265a51f4d828 OP_EQUAL`.

Retrieve those txids like you did in step 3 to construct new spending transaction. Spending transaction will have two inputs. One unlocking 0.005 BTC, another unlocking 0.004 BTC. You need to include corresponding scriptSigs of each input that fulfils the unlocking conditions. Your unlocking condition was 2-3 multisig, so your scriptSig should look like:

```
OP_0 <First Signature> <Second Signature> < OP_2 <First PublicKey> <Second PublicKey> <Third PublicKey> OP_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG >
```

1. `OP_0` is encoded as `0x00` in hex.
2. Say your first DER-encoded signature is 72-bytes, plus one-byte hash code type at the end, plus one-byte length prefix at the beginning is the following:

> 49 30460221AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0221BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 01

3. Say your second DER-encoded signature is also 72-bytes, plus one-byte hash code type at the end, plus one-byte length prefix at the beginning is the following:

> 49
> 30460221CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC0221DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
> 01

4. `< OP_2 <First PublicKey> <Second PublicKey> <Third PublicKey> OP_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG >` plus one-byte length  prefix is encoded in hex:

> 69
> 522103e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb22102df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea29462102102c099a12b6cba679ad56d8e793847f422634bc84b42cb3fae0b00a6943f56921253ae

Your scriptSig in hex will look like:

> 0x004930460221AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0221BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB014930460221CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC0221DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD0169522103e33af80b92e4efd64852166d6126e10aafdcc741579c67c6aa9eb89080cebeb22102df4bf6a54f79b333b7796d2941de13b1755c00c09f4dbf696c7729aea29462102102c099a12b6cba679ad56d8e793847f422634bc84b42cb3fae0b00a6943f56921253ae

Construct scriptSig for the other input as well. You will need to customise your php code in order to achieve all this.

Comment: Well, again thanks for taking the time to put a detailed reply. I edited my question because I followed a tutorial (I added the link at the end) where it explains how to achieve my desired result without calculating manually scripts, I found a couple of errors, the redeemscript is properly calculated now but when I try to sign the transaction it says that redeemscript/witnessscript does not match scriptPubKey... Also being honest it is being hard to follow the process using bitcoin script and DER encoding as I am new to this, but I have been reading all day about it from official website

Comment: By the way, do you have any email or other external way to contact you? If you accept donations I would like to send you a donation once I have it working

Comment: You can reach me at burak@credentialsapp.org